# Touch Image Zooming in android

Tags: android, xml, zooming, touchimageview

I got a series of images in a gallery and was trying to add in the zooming functionality for the same. I read a lot on zooming in android. Worked out various examples. Finally i could create a project to zoom images by drawing that particular image from the drawable folder without using any xml file. It is shown below

I created a java class called Zooming.java

```
public class Zooming extends ImageView {

    Matrix matrix;

    //3 states for zooming 
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    PointF last = new PointF();
    PointF start = new PointF();
    float minScale = 1f;
    float maxScale = 3f;
    float[] m;

    int viewWidth, viewHeight;
    static final int CLICK = 3;
    float saveScale = 1f;
    protected float origWidth, origHeight;
    int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;

    ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

    Context context;

    public Zooming(Context context) {
        super(context);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    public Zooming(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        sharedConstructing(context);
    }

    private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
        super.setClickable(true);
        this.context = context;
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        matrix = new Matrix();
        m = new float[9];
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

        setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x;
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y;
                        float fixTransX = getFixDragTrans(deltaX, viewWidth,
                                origWidth * saveScale);
                        float fixTransY = getFixDragTrans(deltaY, viewHeight,
                                origHeight * saveScale);
                        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
                        fixTrans();
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y);
                    }
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    break;
                }

                setImageMatrix(matrix);
                invalidate();
                return true; // indicate event was handled
            }

        });
    }

    public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
        maxScale = x;
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mode = ZOOM;
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float origScale = saveScale;
            saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
            if (saveScale > maxScale) {
                saveScale = maxScale;
                mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
            } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
                saveScale = minScale;
                mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
            }

            if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth
                    || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2,
                        viewHeight / 2);
            else
                matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor,
                        detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());

            fixTrans();
            return true;
        }
    }

    void fixTrans() {
        matrix.getValues(m);
        float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
        float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight
                * saveScale);

        if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0)
            matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
    }

    float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        float minTrans, maxTrans;

        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            minTrans = 0;
            maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        } else {
            minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
            maxTrans = 0;
        }

        if (trans < minTrans)
            return -trans + minTrans;
        if (trans > maxTrans)
            return -trans + maxTrans;
        return 0;
    }

    float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
        if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
            return 0;
        }
        return delta;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
                || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
            return;
        oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
        oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

        if (saveScale == 1) {
            float scale;

            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0
                    || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
                return;
            int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
            int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

            Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

            float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
            float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
            scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
            matrix.setScale(scale, scale);

            // Center the image
            float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight
                    - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
            float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth
                    - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
            redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
            redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

            matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

            origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
            origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
            setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
    }
}
```

And the MainActivity class is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Zooming img = new Zooming(this);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_1);
        img.setMaxZoom(4f);
        setContentView(img);
    }
```

It is working fine. I can zoom the pic with ease.
My problem is, i want to zoom the pic by using main.xml file. That is by using an imageview or CustomView (com.ZomThePic.Zooming) and giving the source of image there. I tried by adding the imageview as well as by using the Zooming CustomView in my main.xml

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

<com.zoomthepic.zooming

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:id="@+id/pic_id"

    android:src="@drawable/pic_1"/>


<LinearLayout/>
```

And by changing the code in MainActivity as :

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Zooming img = (Zooming)findViewById(R.id.pic_id);
    img.setMaxZoom(4);
}
```

But Unfortunately the application get ceased. Is it possible to get the zooming effect for the image given in the layout file by adding android:src="@drawable/pic_1"  rather than by defining the pic in a java class with an R.drawable.pic_1 by using the same Zooming java class ?  Can anyone help me to resolve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with

```
<com.zoomthepic.zoom

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:id="@+id/pic_id"

android:src="@drawable/pic_1"/>
```

Instead of com.zoomthepic.zoom, use com.zoomthepic.Zoom
It is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your ID in xml is

```
android:id="@+id/pic"
```

In your code you are looking for ...

```
Zooming img = (Zooming)findViewById(R.id.pic_id);
```

The ID's are wrong.

Comment: Sorry it's pic_id only.